# How to find columns with maximum ratings

Tags: r

This problem has to be done in R only not SQL.
I have a problem where I am given below dataset.

Data Dictionary

UserID – 4848 customers who provided a rating for each movie - (Row)
Movie 1 to Movie 206 – 206 movies for which ratings are provided by 4848 distinct users (Columns)

1) I need to find Which movies have maximum views/ratings?

2) Define the top 5 movies with the least audience

I was able to get the max rating for each movie(column) by below. But after this how do I limit this result with highest rating.. what kind of filter or function can be used.

I used this :

```
dataset <- read.csv("Amazon - Movies and TV Ratings.csv", row.names = 1)
sapply(dataset,max,na.rm=TRUE)
```

This gives me one row with max value fr each col (5,5,2,5,3 etc.)

Sample dataset:

```
                Movie1  Movie2  Movie3  Movie4  Movie5  Movie6


   USer1            5      5      NA     NA     NA     NA
   USer2            NA     NA     2      NA     NA     NA
   USer3            NA     NA     NA      5     NA     NA
   USer4            NA     NA     NA      5     NA     NA
   USer5            NA     NA     NA     NA      5     NA
   USer6            NA     NA     NA     NA      2     NA
   USer7            NA     NA     NA     NA      5     NA
   USer8            NA     NA     NA     NA      2     NA
   USer9            NA     NA     NA     NA      5     NA
   USer10           NA     NA     NA     NA      5     NA
```

Sample data screenshot:
[Amazon rating dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucjmE.png)

Comment: `sapply(t(dataset),max,na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: I'd be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example

Comment: Can you place a sample of data and your expected outcome from that sample?

Comment: @Vin I have uploaded recent dataset and need to figure out below 2 questions.

1) I need to find Which movies have maximum views/ratings? 
2) Define the top 5 movies with the least audience

Comment: For getting the total audience for each movie do `colSums(!is.na(dataset))`

Answer (score 0):

For your first question,

```
data <-cbind(c(1,5,NA,2,3,5,2,3),c(3,NA,4,1,2,1,3,2),c(NA,1,1,3,4,3))
data <- as.data.frame(data)
colnames(data) <- c("Movie1","Movie2","Movie3")
data

apply(data,2,max,na.rm=TRUE)
#Movie1 Movie2 Movie3 
#5      4      4
```

For the second question, I believe - you need to specify the criteria on which you want to say a movie is top one. ex : something like do you want to compare the rating with average rating of that movie?